# Not Installing nwidart/laravel-menus

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, composer-php, laravel-5.8

When I try to install nwidart/laravel-menus using

```
composer require nwidart/laravel-menus
```

getting error

> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

- php version ": "^7.1.3"
- laravel/framework version: "5.8.*"
  [click here to see error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dddzI.png)

Comment: Need more details on what exactly the error is, also paste your complete composer.json to better understand or to reproduce.

Comment: Does `composer require nwidart/laravel-menus:"^4.0"` help? If not, please share more details

Comment: Stop using PHP 7.1 as it is no longer [supported](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php)

Answer (score -1):

If you want exactly

> nwidart/laravel-menus

use laravel version between 5 to 8, I used laravel 8

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel <proj_name> "8.*"`

then

`composer require nwidart/laravel-menus`

that worked for me!

Comment: Please edit your original answer, you placed a second one. And welcome to Stack Overflow (SO)!